# Cannot open lockfile /var/spool/cron/atjobs/.SEQ

Tags: php, apache, debian, at-job

I currently made a feature that makes use of the `ATD` service in a php 7.3 image with the `Debian` 10 operating system.

ATD works fine in development, but when I upload the image to the rancher and try to schedule the job with `ATD` using apache (`www-data`) it gives me this error `Cannot open lockfile /var/spool/cron /atjobs/.SEQ`

I searched the internet about this problem, but none of them solve my problem.

Note:

The user `www-data` is inside `at.allow`

The `.SEQ` file is already owned by `deamon:daemon`

Comment: According to `atd(8)` _/var/spool/cron/atspool The directory for storing output; this should be mode 700, owner daemon._ which means none but the owner have any permissions to read or write to that directory. You should be using the `atd` daemon directly to manage changes to the jobs not writing to the files yourself.

Comment: strange, because I can create an AT JOB logged in with the user `www-data`


`sudo su -l www-data -s /bin/bash`

www-data@DESKTOP-KRML6AR:~/AT-TEST$ `echo 'echo testing >> at.log' | at now+1minute`
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 166 at Sun Aug  1 11:37:00 2021


www-data@DESKTOP-KRML6AR:~$ `atq`
163     Sun Aug  1 11:37:00 2021 a www-data

www-data@DESKTOP-KRML6AR:~/AT-TEST$ `ls`
at.log

www-data@DESKTOP-KRML6AR:~/AT-TEST$ `cat at.log`
testing

Comment: Please share more details. How is this problem related to PHP or Apache? Is it related to programming after all?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after deleting an `.SEQ` file in the `spool` directory. What helped me was to change file permission to `777` and then `stop` and `start` the **ATD Service**.

Answer (score -1):

Added full permission to **cron** folder under a /var/spool. it is working fine.

/var/spool# chmod 777 cron/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).